# Make variables available to the Async calls without closures

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am kind of beginner to javascript. I was trying to find out a way to work around nested functions. Take a look at below 2 examples

```
// example 1
var x = 45;
function apple(){
    var y = 60;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(y);
        console.log(x);
    }, 20);
}
apple();
console.log(x);
```

Well the value `y` is maintained and its printed on console since `setTimeout` forms closure with the function `apple()` and it works well. Now take a look at below code

```
var x = 45;
var run = function(){
        console.log(y);
        console.log(x);
}; 
function apple(){
    var y = 60;
    setTimeout(run, 20);
}
apple();
console.log(x);
```

I just wanted to place the function body separately and pass the function handler as argument but the thing I am stuck up is how do I make variables of function `apple()` available to function `run()` because they do not form closure anymore. Is there a workaround to make it possible? Kindly help me.

Please answer me in a generic way, so that it would be applicable to nodejs API also. I have seen `setTimeout` accepts more arguments but I want the solution to be applicable irrespective of function prototype.

**Update**

Sorry but I think all the answers do the function call using pass by value. Its not achieving closures. They take current `y` value and pass it as function argument and Assume there is a statement of `y = 80` after `setTimeout()` like below code

```
var y = 60;
setTimeout(run, 20);
y = 80;
```

It prints y = 60 and not the 80 inside `run()`. I actually want to maintain the reference of y and not capturing its value like how closures do. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var x = 45;
var run = function(y){
        console.log(y);
        console.log(x);
}; 
function apple(){
    var y = 60;
    setTimeout(run.bind(null, y), 20);
}
apple();
console.log(x);
```

The first argument for bind is what you'll want to bind to `this`. After that each argument is passed to the newly created function - notice that I added `y` as an argument to the `run` function.

What `bind` gives you is a new function with a predefined context (`this`) and possibly default values for arguments.

Do note though that you should always avoid scenarios like this. It's never a good idea to modify external variables inside a function, and it will lead to much grief and going gray prematurely. You should try to refactor your code so that you can pass and return values, and not rely on references or globally scoped variables.

Comment: Sorry but I dont think the above code captures by reference. It actually captures by value. For instance, assume there is y  = 80 after setTimeout statement. The setTimeout handler prints 60 and not the 80.

Comment: This solution does not work as closures does. See my updated question Thank you as well

Comment: @user3205479 Primitive values are always passed by value. What you're asking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your `y` variable is not in `run()`'s scope so you need to pass it to `run`. You also can pass run as a parameter to the `apple(cb_fn)` https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/ttxxpoof/

```
var x = 45;
var y = 80;
var run = function(){ 
  console.log('could be 80 or 85(depending on race condition): ' + y);
  console.log('should be 45: ' + x);
}; 

function apple(cb_fn){
  var y = 60; // you can declar var y again to have another ignore global y
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('should be 60: ' + y);
    cb_fn(); // this would be a callback function
  }, 20);
}

apple(run); // you need to pass run in as a "callback" function
console.log('should be 45: ' + x);
y = 85;
console.log('should be 85: ' + y);
```

Comment: You seem to be setting up a race condition which isn't a great idea. I have updated my code though

Answer (score 0):

You could do with y the same you do with x (setting it up as a global).

Comment: sorry but it prints 60

Comment: You made variable "y" as global please its defined inside apple. I know if its made global its possible but iam not interested in creating global variables, if apple has 100 variables then do i need to make all variables globals? Provide right solution

Comment: You are asking for opposing requirements. I'm not wasting any more time on you.